# Weird Android error

Tags: android, android-intent, android-logcat

I'm trying to run my start my app, but i get a weird error. I've changed my OS but I've imported my projects in my Workspace. What can be wrong? Every thing is added to the maniferst file like is should, and this app was running nice before I change my OS.

```
12-13 18:48:10.578: W/dalvikvm(19830): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/darkovski/quran/Main; (56)
12-13 18:48:10.578: W/dalvikvm(19830): Link of class 'Lcom/darkovski/quran/Main;' failed
12-13 18:48:10.578: D/AndroidRuntime(19830): Shutting down VM
12-13 18:48:10.578: W/dalvikvm(19830): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210)
12-13 18:48:10.598: E/AndroidRuntime(19830): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 18:48:10.598: E/AndroidRuntime(19830): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.darkovski.quran/com.darkovski.quran.Main}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.darkovski.quran.Main
12-13 18:48:10.598: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1891)
12-13 18:48:10.598: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
12-13 18:48:10.598: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
12-13 18:48:10.598: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
12-13 18:48:10.598: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-13 18:48:10.598: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 18:48:10.598: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
12-13 18:48:10.598: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 18:48:10.598: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-13 18:48:10.598: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-13 18:48:10.598: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-13 18:48:10.598: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-13 18:48:10.598: E/AndroidRuntime(19830): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.darkovski.quran.Main
12-13 18:48:10.598: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
12-13 18:48:10.598: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-13 18:48:10.598: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-13 18:48:10.598: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
12-13 18:48:10.598: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1882)
12-13 18:48:10.598: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    ... 11 more
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.darkovski.quran"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.darkovski.quran.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.darkovski.quran.Playlist"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.darkovski.quran.AlbumDetails"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <service
            android:name=".MediaPlayerService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.darkovski.quran.Favorites"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.darkovski.quran.DownloadManager"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Your activities' names should not be fully qualified. Replace `android:name="com.darkovski.quran.DownloadManager"` with `android:name=".DownloadManager"` and so on for every activity.

Comment: Then you probably need to clean and rebuild your project. Check that your sources are properly setup in the corresponding directories (e.g. 'src/com/darkovski/quran/Main.java') and that the package name is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Manifest. It is because somehow the super class of your class com/darkovski/quran/Main is not getting loaded in the apk which leads to a class not found.

Try cleaning and rebuilding the project or restarting eclipse. Just check if all the libraries are present in the new workspace and are build properly.